# CREATE LOGIN [$(USERDOMAIN)\MyWinADGroup] not working inside MS VS Project

Tags: sql-server, logins, active-directory

I have 4 Windows AD Domains and the same AD Group within them:

- DEV\MyADGroup
- SIT\MyADGroup
- UAT\MyADGroup
- PROD\MyADGroup

The domains are separated from each other and not trusted, so we can prevent data/access spillage across domains.

I also have 4 SQL instances, one for each domain.

In a MS VS database solution, I'd like to do something like:

```
CREATE LOGIN [$(USERDOMAIN)\MyADGroup]
FROM WINDOWS
GO
```

but I get the error:

> SQL70604: SqlCmd variable reference is not allowed in object names ($(USERDOMAIN)\MyADGroup).

Is there some way to allow the MS VS project to understand that it should dynamically fill in the USERDOMAIN variable at Build-Time, so I can generate diff scripts and publish the solution easily to all 4 domains, without having to manually set the correct domain?

Things I've tried:

- the above, which throws the error
- post-execution scripts, which breaks diff script generation and publishing

Note: this quesion has nothing to do with database-level users, roles, permissions!
We are talking about Windows AD Groups across different Windows AD domains,
and how to map them to a SQL Server Instance-level Login!

Comment: You can't use variables. Don't assign permissions directly to logins either, use roles. This way the only thing you really need to do is to assign the different accounts to roles in a post-build script

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think I finally understand what you're suggesting. I should create new custom Server Roles inside my MS VS project, and use a post-deployment script (which allows variables) to add any Server Logins to the Server Role. Is that it? Do you want to write it up as an answer?

Comment: @Oreo do you really need *server* roles, or database roles?

Comment: @HardCode not sure, happy to use database roles, if one can directly assign Windows AD Groups to them without server roles or server logins.